# Slick Carousel: How to disable blur edges on carousel images?

Tags: css, slick.js

I work on website with a lot of sliders, I use slick-js for them:
https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Everything works as it should, but I noticed that edges of images has 1px blured area which prevents me from adjusting the custom buttons on the sliders.

[image: Screenshot: How to disable blur edges on slick carousel]

Please see the image edges on screenshot there are a tiny line (1px) on each side of image which I would to remove.

I search on the plugin page, but without success.
Here is the sample code of one carousel, the rest are same:

```
$('#TRANSPORTATIONTRANSLOADINGCarousel').slick({
        infinite: true,
        speed: 900,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: randomIntFromInterval(),
        arrows: false,
        fade: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        pauseOnFocus: false,
        swipe: false,
        cssEase: 'linear'
    });
```

If you can't see the blured line, please use Windows key + "+" to enable Magnifier.

How can I remove the blured edges of images on slick carousels?

Comment: which type of images are used? png or jpg?

Comment: I use jpg images

Comment: Can u plz share the images or jsfiddle?

Comment: Here is a link to images which I use on carousels :https://imgur.com/a/JnZnXZx

Comment: Any update for this issue?